# Converting Freemarker To PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, freemarker, template-engine

I am designing reports using freemarker, I have a problem where I need the processed output in a PDF format.

What I want to do is to pass an HTML + CSS fremarker template to the freemarker engine and output the processed HTML as an PDF. The current problem I have is on how to convert the processed freemarker to a PDF

```
    try {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        Template tpl = cfg.getTemplate("example.ftl");
        OutputStreamWriter output = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);

        Map testHashMap = new HashMap();
        testHashMap.put("test", "testValue");

        tpl.process(testHashMap, output);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

While searching on thje internet I couldnt find any information on this topic, but I found out about the iText framework

```
try {
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream(buf.toString()));
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocument(doc, null);
    renderer.layout();
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    renderer.createPDF(os);
    os.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The problem now is how do I combine these two code fragments to generate a pdf?

All help is really appreciated

Regards,
MilindaD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it would be better to use two different pipelines and see them as two different views of the same model.

Data -> Freemarker transfomer -> HTML

Data -> iText transformer -> pdf

or you could use XSLT on the html and use XSL-FO like Apache FOP, but it seems overkill to me.

Answer (score 6):

I would **NOT** suggest to use **iText** as it comes under **AGPL** license.

If you provide a service based on software you got under AGPL licensing, you need to provide free access to the complete software for the service (probably with the limits implied by the “mere aggregation” concept).

You can use [openhtmtopdf](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf) for commercial purpose as well for free as it comes under LGPL license.

Comment: Openhtmltopdf might unfortunately not be developed actively anymore since 2022: https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/commits/open-dev-v1.

Answer (score 0):

Pupeteer seems to be a good option. You can run a separate node process to access your API and print.

https://blog.risingstack.com/pdf-from-html-node-js-puppeteer/